# Node.js диалоги

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Здравствуйте. Требуется написать некоторое подобие диалогов как в вк (строго для двоих). И по виду должен быть механизм следующего вида:

1. При входе в диалог выдаем 5 последних сообщений
2. При отправлении новых сообщений они посредством (`Socket.io`) передаются между 2-умя участниками диалога, и пишутся в базу.

Вопрос в механизме взаимодействия и в том, как мне обрабатывать несколько диалогов сразу, а не один (`socket.io`). Если будут диалоги между, например пользователями, [1,2] [1,3] [2,3].
Использовать room-функционал в `socket.io` или другое решение? Если можно с линками или простыми примерами. Спасибо.

Comment: В подобных случаях, как не странно, рекомендуется открыть заглавную страницу [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) и справа внизу найти ссылку на [A guided introduction to Node](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I). Там автор ноды рассказывает о ней и где то в середине показывает как сделать простенький чат.

Answer (score 3):

Умение искать и анализировать - очень важные качества для программиста.
[раз](http://habrahabr.ru/post/141013/)
[два](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127525/)
[тут подборка похожего](http://habrahabr.ru/search/?q=%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82+%D0%BD%D0%B0+socket.io)

от себя замечу, что лично мне более подошел [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client), чем socket.io

Answer (score 0):

Воспользовался функционалом комнат socket.io.

[@deivan](/users/3579/deivan), супер дельный ответ! Это я и без вас нагуглил, спасибо.